# CodeClimate Not reading configuration

Tags: software-quality, code-climate

In my react project the code quality checker CodeClimate, using advanced [configuration](https://docs.codeclimate.com/docs/advanced-configuration) just stop some silly code quality factors/thresholds like 50 line of code, :

```
Function `AutocompleteCombobox` has 50 lines of code (exceeds 25 allowed). Consider refactoring.
```

what I did I create `.codeclimate.yml` besides my `package.json` and upload that to the repo (connected with CodeClimate on branch DEV), following [documentation](https://docs.codeclimate.com/docs/default-analysis-configuration#sample-codeclimateyml).

this is the example of the `.yml` file:

```
version: "2"         # required to adjust maintainability checks

checks:
  argument-count:
    enabled: true
    config:
      threshold: 4
  complex-logic:
    enabled: true
    config:
      threshold: 4
```

---

**The Question is:** CodeClimate doesn’t changes the records and metrics based on my configuration file!! **I CHANGED THE RECORDS** via `.yml` file; but still not updated on CodeClimate website ?!! the metrics are same as default.

*** TIP: Nothing to do from CodeClimate website settings we stop every condition, nothing apply except default! and I don’t want to delete and re-add the repo's because I'ill lose my tracking records in enhancement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is simple, the server make file called `.codeclimate.json` because I edit the configurations via the website, but in my repo I made I file called `.codeclimate.yml`, when I convert the configuration from `.yml` to `.json` I override the one on the server that works perfectly.

Example for may configuration `.codeclimate.json`:

```
    {
      "version": "2",
      "checks": {
        "argument-count": {
          "enabled": false,
          "config": {
            "threshold": 4
          }
        },
        "complex-logic": {
          "enabled": true,
          "config": {
            "threshold": 15
          }
        },
        "file-lines": {
          "enabled": false,
          "config": {
            "threshold": 250
          }
        },
        "method-complexity": {
          "enabled": true,
          "config": {
            "threshold": 15
          }
        },
        "method-count": {
          "enabled": false,
          "config": {
            "threshold": 20
          }
        },
        "method-lines": {
          "enabled": false,
          "config": {
            "threshold": 25
          }
        },
        "nested-control-flow": {
          "enabled": true,
          "config": {
            "threshold": 4
          }
        },
        "return-statements": {
          "enabled": true,
          "config": {
            "threshold": 4
          }
        },
        "similar-code": {
          "enabled": false,
          "config": {
            "threshold": null
          }
        },
        "identical-code": {
          "enabled": true,
          "config": {
            "threshold": null
          }
        }
      },
      "exclude_patterns": [
        "config/",
        "db/",
        "dist/",
        "features/",
        "**/node_modules/",
        "script/",
        "**/spec/",
        "**/test/",
        "**/tests/",
        "Tests/",
        "**/vendor/",
        "**/*_test.go",
        "**/*.d.ts"
      ]
    }
```

**If you face the same issue probably the configuration is duplicated on CodeClimate, you need to use one file only.**

[image]